# Unable to run "play" with sbt in git

Tags: git, playframework, sbt

I am trying to launch play from two different consoles :

1) Classic windows cmd and it works without any problem

2) Git

And I get the following error :

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0
Error during sbt execution: Could not find configuration file 'c:/play/play-2.2.3/framework/sbt/sbt.boot.properties'.  Searched:
        file:/c:/users/aso/Desktop/helloworld/
        file:/C:/Users/aso/
        file:/C:/play/play-2.2.3/framework/sbt/
```

What I really don't get is that the sbt.boot.properties is in the C:/play/play-2.2.3/framework/sbt ...

Any idea what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Check you version of sbt, as it was recently fixed in [sbt/sbt-launcher-package issue 96](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package/pull/96) in [`src/universal/bin/sbt#L40`](https://github.com/TLmaK0/sbt-launcher-package/blob/92a06fc5da81ce05a28ee1239e3a99752e067218/src/universal/bin/sbt#L40)

Also check your version of git, making sure you are using [the latest one (2.8.1)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).